# Database stuck in executing query or slow SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-connection

**UPDATE** : I tried re-creating another table in that the same database and was able to run select statement just fine. I also tried

```
SELECT * FROM [UNNIK].[dbo].[leads] WITH(NOLOCK) ORDER BY id DESC ;
```

which now works. But this is a temporary solution I want to know what is going on?

We have a Database Server which has 50 plus Databases in it. Some are more than 50GB of size but this morning there is this one Database that is running slow or not responding in the query.

This is the only database that doesn't work. Others works fine and this database is just small with 20,000 records only.

When I run a query like

```
SELECT * FROM [UNNIK].[dbo].[leads] ORDER BY id DESC;
```

It will be just stuck in `executing query` status with the circle progress animation.

Even limiting it to 1 query  doesn't show anything.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [UNNIK].[dbo].[leads] ORDER BY id DESC;
```

What could be the problem? I am no expert in Database trouble shooting. I am a PHP Developer and most of the knowledge I know in Database is just those queries related to my PHP scripting. I tried inserting a record in the database and it works fine. Just the select statement doesn't work or queries that has something to do with viewing.

Comment: You miss an index on Id column

Comment: @Polux2 How do I fix that?

Comment: I tried CREATE INDEX id_index ON [UNNIK].[dbo].[leads] (id); but samething.

Comment: Is the performance the same without the order by clause? What if you select top 1 without an order?

Comment: Do you have an uncommitted transaction?  Try running: COMMIT TRANSACTION.

Comment: @SeanR Same thing. I did update my question I found a temporary solution SELECT * FROM [UNNIK].[dbo].[leads] WITH(NOLOCK) ORDER BY id DESC ;

Comment: @E.Monk We don't use Transactional queries so it's not it.

Comment: @JoeneFloresca if you are able to run it with nolock then something is locking the table... run sp_lock/sp_who and find it.

Comment: Can you please provide the table schema?, just to discard if you have varbinary, varchar(max), text etc, try reading a single column like the PK or other that is indexed, remove the order by + top 1 as @SeanR mentioned, you can also use the [sp_whoisactive](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/09/sql-server-dba-scripts-how-to-find-slow-sql-server-queries/)

Comment: @JoeneFloresca All Transact SQL queries are transactional, whether explicitly stated or not.